# Is loud dhikr in group allowed?

Tags: dhikr

I understand that there are arguments that [loud dhikr is not part of the sunnah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/40913/15201) (because there are no explicit ahadith speaking about that).

**Question:** Is loud dhikr in group allowed?

There might be different of opinions about this, which might be highly related to the definition of innovation/bidah one has.

*Please provide good references. A bonus would be if you added what definition of bidah/innovation the scholar has.* If you disagree with one answer, add you own.

Comment: Related https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36198/why-do-some-masajid-ask-us-to-read-surah-fatiha-in-dua

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes it is related, but seems to be restricted about "al-faitha", and "why some masjids...." - I hope this question is more general and will provide specific answers.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I think that the answer could be used here but edited a bit, because "dhikr" as you know isn't restricted to dua or fatiha

Comment: you  may check this link. https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/156

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to acts of worship, they have to be clearly and precisely established by the Qur’ân and Sunnah. Anything else is an unlawful innovation (bid`ah). The burden of proof, therefore, is upon the one claiming that some act is an act of worship.

Therefore reading Quran in unison in a gathering or sending salawat on the prophet peace be upon him in unison and in a gathering is nowhere found in the books hadith.

The proofs the previous reply presented are weak and already established at specific times and specific places. Which he cannot then draw a deduction for unison thikr at other times and places in unison. Yes, there are various ahadith which are found that state reward of making thikr in gatherings, such as, narrated by Muslim (2701)

> From Mu‘aawiyah ibn Abi Sufyaan (may Allah be pleased with him), according to which the Messenger of Allaah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) came out to a circle of his companions and said: “Why are you sitting here?” They said: We are sitting to remember Allaah and praise Him for having guided us to Islam and blessed us with it. He said: “By Allaah, are you only sitting for that purpose? They said: By Allaah, we are only sitting for that purpose. He said: “I did not ask you to swear because I am accusing you, but Jibreel came to me and told me that Allaah was boasting of you to the angels.”

And the report also narrated by Muslim (2699) from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) who said:

> The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “No people gather in one of the houses of Allaah, reciting the Book of Allaah and studying it together, but tranquillity will descend upon them, mercy will overshadow them, the angels will surround them and Allaah will mention them to those who are with Him.”

–     There is nothing in these reports to suggest that dhikr should be recited in unison. But they can speak about the favors of Allah upon them, discuss business according to sunnah or remember the greatness of Allah. Which is all considered thikr and in a group.

The point is these ahadith and the implementation of them was already there during the time of prophet pbuh and his companions. And none of them understood them as unison thikr or unison Quran recitation with a single voice, as the brother before this answered. Which if it was, they would have acted upon it before us. This implies there was a shortcoming in the  understanding the companions regarding our beloved prophet pbuh sayings.Which we now understand. Which is impossibble. Our best recouse is to refer all matters back to Allah and his messenger.

As Allah says:-

> "If you differ in anything among yourselves, refer it to Allah and His Messenger, if you believe in Allah and the Last Day. That is best and most commendable in the end." [Al-Qur'an 4:59].

He also says:-

> "And whatever you disagree upon, its decision is with Allah." [Al-Qur'an 42:10].

And whoso opposeth the messenger after the guidance (of Allah) hath been manifested unto him, and followeth other than the believer's ( sahaba) way, We appoint for him that unto which he himself hath turned, and expose him unto hell - a hapless journey's end!
(Nisaa verse 115)

So fear Allah with regards your religion and who you take it from.
The best of guidance is the book Allah and the best actions is the that of the prophet pbuh.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Could you verify which opinion you follow on the definition of innovations?   Is it the more strict one (i.e all bidahs are bad) or the less strict?

Comment: All of the early scholars had the same definitions regarding good innovation and where it can apply and bad. For example"bn Hajar al-Asqalani, Ibn Qayyim al-Jawziyya, Muhammad ash-Shawkani and imam Nawawi to name a few. All of them stated innovation in sharia and worship are reprehensible. If their is contradictions in my references concerning these scholors.. proof is required. Hope that answers your qustion.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve been thinking about this lately, and yes while there is a disagreement amongst the scholars, this is the best conclusion I came to believe.

Loud Dhikr in groups is **not** a bidah/innovation. Evidence for that is the Prophet PBUH reciting Talbiya with his companions. If Loud Dhikr was such a transgression in this religion, then there would be no “Allahuma Labaika, Laka Lhamd wa Shukr” - This is literally a loud Dhikr done in congregation every year.

How about when Muslims join in Takbeer (in Salah or otherwise) and during other numerous incidents when no one bats an eye about this?

How about when the Muslims respond with “Rabana Laka L Hamd” after “Samia Lahu Li Man Hamidah” during the congregation Salah?

How about the Quran where Allah commands the mountains to praise Him along with Dawud PBUH and the birds? Is that not a congregation Dhikr?

How about in madrasas where the students are all reciting the Quran in the same time?  Is that not a form of congregation based Dhikr?

What is a Bidah/Innovation, in my opinion, is coming in and limiting the Muslims congregational loud dhikr in only certain incidents. This sounds nothing short of intellectual dishonesty. The only loud Dhikr that has been disliked is the Dhikr that annoys other people around you.

> Hadith no: 623
>   Narrated / Authority Of: Anas bin Malik
>   Allah's Apostle offered four Rakat of Zuhr prayer at Medina and we were in his company, and two Rakat of the Asr prayer at Dhul-Hulaifa and then passed the night there till it was dawn; then he rode, and when he reached Al-Baida', he praised and glorified Allah and said Takbir (i.e. Alhamdu-lillah and Subhanallah(1) and Allahu-Akbar). **Then he and the people along with him recited Talbiya with the intention of performing Hajj and Umra**. When we reached (Mecca) he ordered us to finish the lhram (after performing the Umra) (only those who had no Hadi (animal for sacrifice) with them were asked to do so) till the day of Tarwiya that is 8th Dhul-Hijja when they assumed Ihram for Hajj. The Prophet sacrificed many camels (slaughtering them) with his own hands while standing. While Allah's Apostle was in Medina he sacrificed two horned rams black and white in color in the Name of Allah."
>   Sahih Bukhari, Chapter 26

And Allah SWT knows best.

Comment: Most of your examples seem to show practices that are marginal and are rather wrong: Except for the Imam none is allowed to raise his voice in the prayer! Reciting the quran in the same time -loudly- is rather in best case makrooh!

Comment: @Medi1Saif why would you consider the Dhikr during hajj as marginal?

Comment: I pointed at what is wrong practice hajj is none of that.

Comment: @Medi1Saif So what would you consider the “Allahuma labaik” chant?

Comment: It is something prescribed by Allah