# What is it like to mention Allah aloud after praying inside the mosque? (zikr o llah)

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, dhikr

Today I’m with some of my friends which belongs to very Islamic cultural background, while talking about sharia one of my friend tell us that to recite wazaif ( tasbihat) is not good. I’m surprised for a while then I think that I get guidance about this daily life matter from your people. So let me know either it is wrong or right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The statement of your friend either is a bit blurry and needs some clarification or he is somewhat wrong.

First of all doing dhikr after the prayer actually is confirmed in the qur'an and the sunnah (I'll add or link evidences later).

What actually is the major issue is whether or not dhikr in a group and aloud is shari'a conform. And even in this we must differ between two different opinions:

- It is allowed with the intention to teach the audience the wording of dhikr. However this would mean that for example the imam would recite a dhikr or a part of it and the audience would repeat it (which is rarly the case).
- It is bid'ah as the prophet () nor his companions or their followers never did so.

Practically this means as long as you do dhikr on your own and in silence you are on the safe side.

See also these relevant posts:
[Is loud dhikr in group allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40940/is-loud-dhikr-in-group-allowed)
[Why do some masajid ask us to read Surah Fatiha in dua?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36198/why-do-some-masajid-ask-us-to-read-surah-fatiha-in-dua)
[Is it sunnah of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) to do zikr in a loud voice?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40897/is-it-sunnah-of-prophet-muhammad-peace-be-upon-him-to-do-zikr-in-a-loud-voice?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score -1):

> Today I’m with some of my friends which belongs to very Islamic cultural background, while talking about sharia one of my friend tell us that to recite wazaif ( tasbihat) is not good.

There's nothing wrong with doing zikr out loud so long as you are not disturbing other people; and if you are not doing this to attract attention to your own piety.

> Say, "Whether you conceal what is in your breasts or reveal it, Allah knows it. And He knows that which is in the heavens and that which is on the earth. And Allah is over all things competent. 
>   Qu'ran 3:29